# problema de id já existe na visualização

Tags: primefaces, xhtml

Olá, pessoal. Estou com um arquivo .xhtml que está dando um erro de id já encontrado na visualização. O erro em si é

**GRAVE: JSF1007: ID de componente duplicada frmPesquisa:id encontrada na visualização.**

Eu pesquisei na internet sobre este erro mas as respostas que encontrei são relativamente vagas e não consegui utilizá-las para resolver o meu problema.

Estou postando o arquivo da página xhtl que está dando problema. Postarei também o código de outra página que está usando o mesmo id (frmPesquisa) e está dando certo.

Para reforçar, **a página que está dando erro é a página PesquisaPropriedade.xhtml. O arquivo da página PesquisaUsuario.xhtml é somente para comparação.**

**PesquisaPropriedade.xhtml**

```
<ui:define name="titulo">Pesquisar Propriedades</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">
    <h:form id="frmPesquisa">
    <p:messages showDetail="false" showSummary="true" autoUpdate="true" />

    <h1>Pesquisa de propriedades</h1>

    <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
        <p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:commandButton value="Pesquisar" action="#{pesquisaPropriedadeBean.pesquisar}" update="@form" />
            <p:selectOneRadio id="id" value="#{pesquisaPropriedadeBean.filtro.status}" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ativo" itemValue="Ativo" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Inativo" itemValue="Inativo" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
        <p:toolbarGroup align ="right">
            <p:button value="Novo" outcome="/propriedade/CadastroPropriedade"/>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
    </p:toolbar>

    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
        <p:outputLabel value="id" for="id"/>
        <p:inputText id="id" size="60" maxlength="80"
        value="#{pesquisaPropriedadeBean.filtro.propriedadeId}"/>
    </p:panelGrid>

    <p:dataTable id="propriedadesTable"
            value="#{pesquisaPropriedadeBean.propriedadesFiltradas}" var="propriedade"
            style="margin-top: 20px" emptyMessage="Nenhuma propriedade encontrada."
            rows="20" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
            paginatorPosition="bottom">

    <p:column headerText="Id" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{propriedade.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Nome" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{propriedade.nome}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Proprietário" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{propriedade.usuario}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Área" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{propriedade.area}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="matrícula" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{propriedade.matricula}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Estado" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{propriedade.estado}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Cidade" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{propriedade.cidade}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Endereço" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{propriedade.endereco}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Status" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{propriedade.status}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Operações" style="width: 100px; text-align: center">
    <c:set var ="status" scope = "session"/>
            <p:button outcome = "/propriedade/CadastroPropriedade" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Editar" disabled ="#{pesquisaPropriedadeBean.inativo}">
                <f:param name="propriedade" value="#{propriedade.id}" />
            </p:button>
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-bloquear" title="Alterar status do cadastro" oncomplete="PF('confirmacaoExclusao').show()" process="@this" update="frmPesquisa:confirmacaoExclusaoDialog">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{propriedade}" target="#{pesquisaPropriedadeBean.propriedadeSelecionada}"/>    
            </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>


    </p:dataTable>

        <p:confirmDialog header="Alterar status do cadastro"
            message="Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status do cadastro do usuário #{pesquisaUsuarioBean.usuarioSelecionado.nome}?"
            widgetVar="confirmacaoExclusao" id="confirmacaoExclusaoDialog">
            <p:button value="Não"
                onclick="PF('confirmacaoExclusao').hide(); return false;" />
            <p:commandButton value="Sim"
                oncomplete="PF('confirmacaoExclusao').hide();" action="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.excluir}" process="@this" update="frmPesquisa:propriedadesTable"/>
        </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
</ui:define>
```

**PesquisaUsuario.xhtml**

```
<ui:define name="titulo">Pesquisar Usuarios</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">
    <h:form id="frmPesquisa">
    <p:messages showDetail="false" showSummary="true" autoUpdate="true" />

    <h1>Pesquisa de usuários</h1>

    <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
        <p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:commandButton value="Pesquisar" action="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.pesquisar}" update="@form" />
            <p:selectOneRadio id="id" value="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.filtro.status}" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ativo" itemValue="Ativo" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Inativo" itemValue="Inativo" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
        <p:toolbarGroup align ="right">
            <p:button value="Novo" outcome="/usuario/CadastroUsuario"/>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
    </p:toolbar>

    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
        <p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome"/>
        <p:inputText id="nome" size="60" maxlength="80"
        value="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.filtro.nome}"/>
    </p:panelGrid>

    <p:dataTable id="usuariosTable"
            value="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.usuariosFiltrados}" var="usuario"
            style="margin-top: 20px" emptyMessage="Nenhum usuario encontrado."
            rows="20" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
            paginatorPosition="bottom">

    <p:column headerText="Id" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Nome" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.nome}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="RG" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.rg}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="CPF" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.cpf}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Email" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.email}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Telefone" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.telefone}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Celular" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.celular}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Endereço" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.endereco}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Estado" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.estado}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Cidade" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.cidade}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="CEP" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.cep}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Status" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.status}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Operações" style="width: 100px; text-align: center">
    <c:set var ="status" scope = "session"/>
            <p:button outcome = "/usuario/CadastroUsuario" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Editar" disabled ="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.inativo}">
                <f:param name="usuario" value="#{usuario.id}" />
            </p:button>
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-bloquear" title="Alterar status do cadastro" oncomplete="PF('confirmacaoExclusao').show()" process="@this" update="frmPesquisa:confirmacaoExclusaoDialog">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{usuario}" target="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.usuarioSelecionado}"/>    
            </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>


    </p:dataTable>

        <p:confirmDialog header="Alterar status do cadastro"
            message="Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status do cadastro do usuário #{pesquisaUsuarioBean.usuarioSelecionado.nome}?"
            widgetVar="confirmacaoExclusao" id="confirmacaoExclusaoDialog">
            <p:button value="Não"
                onclick="PF('confirmacaoExclusao').hide(); return false;" />
            <p:commandButton value="Sim"
                oncomplete="PF('confirmacaoExclusao').hide();" action="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.excluir}" process="@this" update="frmPesquisa:usuariosTable"/>
        </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Desde já, agradeço qualquer sugestão, opinião ou conselho.

Answer (score 1):

O JSF não permite que você tenha id's iguais, então o que você precisa fazer é mudar o   de alguma das páginas que você postou. Recomendo que você detalhe mais o id, algo como   e  ....

Comment: exato, namecontainers devem ser únicos, complementando sua resposta:
[doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setId-java.lang.String-)        
          
```The specified identifier must be unique among all the components (including facets) that are descendents of the nearest ancestor UIComponent that is a NamingContainer, or within the scope of the entire component tree if there is no such ancestor that is a NamingContainer.```

Comment: Mas a questão é a seguinte: eu possuo no total 4 páginas que estão usando o mesmo id (frmPesquisa) e as outras 3 páginas não estão dando este erro.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do mesmo form você esta utilizando duas vezes mesmo id="id". E isso não pode. Note de no outro formulário ao qual voce mensionou que funciona, você não tem duas vezes o mesmo.

Abaixo os trechos com o ID duplicado.

```
<p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
        <p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:commandButton value="Pesquisar" action="#{pesquisaPropriedadeBean.pesquisar}" update="@form" />
            <p:selectOneRadio id="id" value="#{pesquisaPropriedadeBean.filtro.status}" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ativo" itemValue="Ativo" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Inativo" itemValue="Inativo" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
        <p:toolbarGroup align ="right">
            <p:button value="Novo" outcome="/propriedade/CadastroPropriedade"/>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
    </p:toolbar>

    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
        <p:outputLabel value="id" for="id"/>
        <p:inputText id="id" size="60" maxlength="80"
        value="#{pesquisaPropriedadeBean.filtro.propriedadeId}"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
```